# How to export and import java project with intelij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I am having an issue that I am trying to solve.
I have a java project and I use intelij IDE.
I want to move it to another computer.
I used to work with eclipse and this task was very easy, export as zip and import and open zip.
However in intelij there is no way to do it, it is not support zip.
I searched all the web, and nothing, all the solutions are with git.
all the information on youtube and so are just to import project to intelij, or to export as jar and run the project.
what is the easiest way without using the internet to export project from one intelij using disk on key, and open it and start working on another computer with intelij.
Can anyone provide step by step solution for this question.
I am using 2019 IDE community version
regards

Comment: Can't you just zip up your project folder and then transfer it across to a new machine? Your IDE doesn't need to do it, you can just use any zip tool.

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is "it depends." For many maven projects, the IDE files are not checked in. When you get a new machine, clone the repo and import the project. Yes, you start from scratch, but it is easy. From the IDE, you may have to manually select Java, and setup Maven. Again this depends. Some projects use bundled Java and Maven, and other groups manually install specific versions. So as I said, it depends upon the project.

With Intellij, projects can generally be copied from one directory to another. This means that the paths in the IntelliJ iml files use relative paths.

So this is really a build question. Personally, I want to be able to build from source control. I will check in Intellij runtime configurations, but have git ignore other IDE files.

Perhaps you could clarify what issues you have building from freshly cloned repo.

Answer (score 0):

When you create projects you specify the location where they will reside. By default IntelliJ IDEA suggests a directory under C:\Users\\IdeaProjects.

You can copy the project folder (as to *export* it).

To open a project, you can right click on a project folder and open it as a Java project on IntelliJ IDEA (or) On the IntelliJ IDEA, import the project folder.